# mapping an annulus to a region

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

How can I transform by a conformal mapping the annulus $\{w \in \mathbb{C} : 1<|w|<2\}$ to $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: R(z)>0, |z-h|>1\}$.

I noticed that I need some Möbius transform that turn one disc in another disc (with center $h$) and one disc in a line, so it must be of the form $1/z-a$ where $a$ is some point of the boundary of the circumference but I can't force those conditions to give that specific disc in the image.

Comment: Start with a conformal mapping from $\{w \in \mathbb{C} : |w|> 1 \}$ to the right half-plane.

Comment: is this possible since the annulus is not simply connected?

Comment: I guess $z-1/z+1$ will do it, but how can i send The$ |z|<2$ to that exactly circunference?